# Bootstrap 4: how to reset button loading

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spinner

i'm using this code for loading of buttons

```
<script>
        $('#load1').click(function() {
            $('#load1').html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loading...').attr('disabled', true);
        });
</script>
```

how to setTimeout in this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` function to hide the loading and spinner after `x` seconds of each `button` being clicked.

In order to `return` the button to its `original` state. We need to save the HTML of that clicked button on variable and then apply back that `HTML` back to relevant `clicked` button.

Also use a `class` selector instead of `id` for button click to that you can reuse the same function multiple `loading` message and `spinner` of different having the same class.

Use [prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the `disabled` property `attr` is **not** ideal in this case and is **not** rec-emended to be used

**Live Working Example:**

```js
$('.load1').click(function() {
  var _this = $(this) //click button
  var existingHTML = _this.html() //store exiting button HTML
  //Add loading message and spinner
  $(_this).html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loading...').prop('disabled', true)

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(_this).html(existingHTML).prop('disabled', false) //show original HTML and enable
  }, 3000) //3 seconds
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success load1">
  Click Success
</button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-danger load1">
  Click Danger
</button>
```